Ory Hydra: No CSRF value available in the session cookie
I have an endpoint that attempts the following:
const login = await oidc
    .getOAuth2LoginRequest({ loginChallenge })
    .then(() =>
      oidc
        .acceptOAuth2LoginRequest({
          loginChallenge,
          acceptOAuth2LoginRequest: {
            subject: 'Roy',
            remember: Boolean(false),
            remember_for: 3600,
            acr: '0',
          },
        })
        .then(({ data }) => data))
res.redirect(login.redirect_to)

I receive the following error:
The request is not allowed. No CSRF value available in the session cookie.
If I do the following:
res.status(200).json({message: login.redirect_to})

And follow that returned redirect link from the client, the consent endpoint gets called and everything works
According to this: https://www.ory.sh/docs/oauth2-oidc/custom-login-consent/flow
I should redirect from the api directly.
I'm not sure why this is the case.
My stack is Ory Hydra (local docker env), Nextjs and Next Auth.
Is there anyone able to help?
